# Where can I get road data that includes max speed?

Tags: data

Does anyone know how to detect the road speed

I. E.  If one of our vehicles was driving on a certain road above the speed limit,  we would want to know

But no idea where to get this data from
Any help appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: What part of the world are you in?  That will change were you might get the data from.

Comment: It needs to be international,  but I guess I could use multiple providers?

Answer (score 7):

This kind of data is very expensive. If you don't have many thousands of dollars/euros to spare (a small European country can cost you 20k € per year), your only chance is OSM. Check this road speed visualization from ITO to get a feeling for what kind of data is available: http://www.itoworld.com/map/124

Comment: In Finland there is Digiroad it used to cost 300€ might be cheaper now.

Comment: @simplexio are you sure €300,-- will buy you a license for commercial use?

Comment: see http://www.digiroad.fi/aineisto/en_GB/delivery/ , "Digiroad customers are only charged extraction costs." and "EUR 200 + VAT / delivery format / delivery"

Comment: ITO world doesn't have a solution yet, but they want to do something in future

Can i get this data direct from OSM
I.e. pass in lat and Long and return a speed limit for this position/rd?

Comment: Why don't governments provide this for free? It's public knowledge.